# GCC linker incorrectly defining startup variable

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, linker, linker-scripts

I am trying to initialize some RAM variables from FLASH in a STM32F7 device. The flash is located at `0x8018000` while the RAM position I want to load that flash is at `0x2007A000`

I have my linker file setup as follows:

```
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)     : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 0x7A000-0x1
  RAM_FACTORY (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x2007A000,   LENGTH = 0x2000
  FLASH_FACTORY    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8018000,   LENGTH = 0x8000
}
/* Sections */
SECTIONS
{

    /* Other stuff */

    .factory_variables : {
      KEEP(*(.factory_variables))
    } > FLASH_FACTORY 
  
  _si_factory_data = LOADADDR(.factory_variables);
  /* defining factory variables RAM region */
  .factory_variables : {
   _s_factory_data = .;
    *(.factory_variables)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _e_factory_data = .; 
  } >RAM_FACTORY AT> FLASH_FACTORY
}
```

I can see in my map file  that the variable `_s_factory_data`  is being incorrectly initialized as `0x2007a006` instead of `0x2007a000`

My .map file:

```
.factory_variables
                0x000000002007a000        0x8 load address 0x0000000008018000
 *(.factory_variables)
 .factory_variables
                0x000000002007a000        0x6 ./Em/Src/os/rte/rte.o
                0x000000002007a000                FACTORY_sample_calibration
                0x000000002007a002                FACTORY_sample_calibration1
                0x000000002007a004                FACTORY_sample_calibration2
                0x000000002007a006                _s_factory_data = .
```

If I force the variable value in my start up code the initialization is done correctly. Sample working start up code:

```
 /* Load Factory variables from flash to RAM */
  ldr r0, = 0x2007A000
  ldr r1, =_e_factory_data
  ldr r2, =_si_factory_data
  movs r3, #0
  b LoopCopyDataInitFactory

CopyDataInitFactory:
  ldr r4, [r2, r3]
  str r4, [r0, r3]
  adds r3, r3, #4

LoopCopyDataInitFactory:
  adds r4, r0, r3
  cmp r4, r1
  bcc CopyDataInitFactory
```

Not hardcoding `_s_factory_data` leads to incorrect initialization

```
 /* Load Factory variables from flash to RAM */
  ldr r0, = _s_factory_data
  ldr r1, =_e_factory_data
  ldr r2, =_si_factory_data
  movs r3, #0
  b LoopCopyDataInitFactory

CopyDataInitFactory:
  ldr r4, [r2, r3]
  str r4, [r0, r3]
  adds r3, r3, #4

LoopCopyDataInitFactory:
  adds r4, r0, r3
  cmp r4, r1
  bcc CopyDataInitFactory
```

Any idea of why the `_s_factory_data` is being assigned a memory position after `*(.factory_variables)` even thought its set before those variables?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] that can be assembled and linked to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with linker scripts, but, from: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_chapter/ld_3.html you could try changing `_s_factory_data = .;` into `_s_factory_data = ADDR(.factory_variables);` See the difference between `ADDR` and `LOADADDR` as I think that's what they're there for.

Comment: @CraigEstey the problem is probably in `/* Other stuff */`

Comment: @0___________ In the whole linker file there is no other reference to `factory_variables` , `RAM_FACTORY`, `FLASH_FACTORY`, `_s_factory_data` so I do not see how it could have an effect.

Comment: @CraigEstey Changing the linker to `_s_factory_data = ADDR(.factory_variables);` did indeed fix the issue.