# STM32L151 fails to copy data segment from flash to SRAM

Tags: c, assembly, linker, stm32, cortex-m

Been having a very weird issue with a specific build of a FW. When booting the device, I can see that SRAM isn't being filled with the data I'd expect, this should happen in the entry point function Reset_Handler. It then continues to pull the reset pin every 3.2ms, being stuck in a boot loop.

I can see in the .map file from building, what variables to expect at the start of SRAM, and I don't see that data there. With an older working build, I see the data. The weird thing is, that if the application is loaded for debugging with STM32CubeIDE, it works, but when flashing through ST-Link utility or any of our serial options, letting the device boot on its own, we get the same broken behavior.

The unfortunate thing with everything working while debugging is of course, I can't get any good info as to what leads up to the data not being copied.

If I use STM32CubeProgrammer, it looks like the program counter is stuck at adress 0x20000000, and I am unable to step anywhere.
[View of STM32CubeProgrammer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdhuq.png)

Parts of our linker script:

```
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

...

MEMORY
{
  BOT_FLASH (rx)       : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x6000   /* 24 kB */
  PSB_FLASH (rx)       : ORIGIN = 0x08006000, LENGTH = 0x8000   /* 32 kB */
  FLASH (rx)           : ORIGIN = 0x0800E000, LENGTH = 0x72000  /* 456 kB */
  
  SHARED_DATA (r)      : ORIGIN = 0x08080000, LENGTH = 0x200     /* 2 x 256 bytes in EEPROM */
  SHARED_DATA_END (r)  : ORIGIN = 0x08080200, LENGTH = 0x1       /* end marker */
  RAM (xrw)            : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x13ED0
  RAM_SHARED (rw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20013ED0, LENGTH = 0x20
  PERSISTENT_RAM(xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x20013EF0, LENGTH = 0x110
  MEMORY_B1 (rx)       : ORIGIN = 0x60000000, LENGTH = 0K
}

...

SECTIONS {

 .aBunchOfSectionsInFlash: {
    ...
 } >FLASH

   ...

   _sidata = .;

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */
    *(.RamFunc)        /* .RamFunc sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT>FLASH

...

}
```

.map file

```
Memory Configuration

Name             Origin             Length             Attributes
BOT_FLASH        0x08000000         0x00006000         xr
PSB_FLASH        0x08006000         0x00008000         xr
FLASH            0x0800e000         0x00072000         xr
SHARED_DATA      0x08080000         0x00000200         r
SHARED_DATA_END  0x08080200         0x00000001         r
RAM              0x20000000         0x00013ed0         xrw
RAM_SHARED       0x20013ed0         0x00000020         rw
PERSISTENT_RAM   0x20013ef0         0x00000110         xrw
MEMORY_B1        0x60000000         0x00000000         xr
*default*        0x00000000         0xffffffff

...
                0x080762e4                _sidata = .


.data           0x20000000     0x1380 load address 0x080762e4
                0x20000000                . = ALIGN (0x4)
                0x20000000                _sdata = .

...

                0x20001380                _edata = .
```

Reset_Handler:

```
/**
 * @brief  This is the code that gets called when the processor first
 *          starts execution following a reset event. Only the absolutely
 *          necessary set is performed, after which the application
 *          supplied main() routine is called.
 * @param  None
 * @retval : None
*/
    .section  .text.Reset_Handler
  .weak  Reset_Handler
  .type  Reset_Handler, %function
Reset_Handler:

    /* Setup C - environment, initialise data */
    bl SetupCSys

    /* Low level HW initialization */
    bl  SystemInit

    /* Call */
    bl  main
    bx  lr
.size  Reset_Handler, .-Reset_Handler

/* Provide weak alias for SetupCSys.
 * This will only be called if another definition is not supplied.
*/
.weak      SetupCSys
.thumb_set SetupCSys,Default_SetupCSys

    .section  .text.Default_SetupCSys,"ax",%progbits
  .type Default_SetupCSys, %function
Default_SetupCSys:
    /* Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM */
    movs  r1, #0
    b  LoopCopyDataInit

CopyDataInit:
    ldr  r3, =_sidata
    ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
    str  r3, [r0, r1]
    adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyDataInit:
    ldr  r0, =_sdata
    ldr  r3, =_edata
    adds  r2, r0, r1
    cmp  r2, r3
    bcc  CopyDataInit
    ldr  r2, =_sbss
    b  LoopFillZerobss

FillZerobss:    /* Zero fill the bss segment. */
    movs  r3, #0
    str  r3, [r2], #4

LoopFillZerobss:
    ldr  r3, = _ebss
    cmp  r2, r3
    bcc  FillZerobss
```

I have no idea how to proceed with this. Any suggestions on what I can try?

Comment: For background, see a similar question that I answered: [GCC linker incorrectly defining startup variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75512096/5382650). You may need `ADDR` and `LOADADDR` directives. You're _not_ showing the _address_ values for `_sidata` and `_sdata` [and `_edata`], so we don't know if they're in the correct sections and whether there is a slight [incorrect] offset, similar to the issue in the linked question.

Comment: `0x20000000` is RAM. Have you set the boot pin(s) (and/or boot-pin-like registers) to boot from RAM? That might explain why it won't run from power-on, but does run when the debugger is controlling it.

Comment: Show **full** linker script. The error is in the part you did not show

Comment: @CraigEstey I added some more info in the linker script and map file, is that enough?

Comment: @kruml you need to use loadaddress instead of current pointer

Answer (score 1):

It will not work.

```
_sidata = .;
```

Symbol `_sidata` has a value of the current pointer, not the place where the load address of the `.data` segment is.

You need to assign it with the load address of the segment `.data` (ie where the data is stored in the FLASH)

```
_sidata = LOADADDR(.data);
```

Comment: That did not fix it unfortunately. Not saying it's not a more correct way of doing it, but could you explain to me how the dot operator is wrong in this case? Looking at the map file, to me it looks like .data loads the correct address of _sidata, however I haven't worked with this kind of stuff a lot so can of course misunderstand something.

Comment: @kruml If it does not then you have more problems in your code/linker script.